# Image is not updating when added through Image Picker in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

My motto in this snippet is to get an image from image-picker and show it in place of camera icon.I was trying to update the image by calling setState but its not updating even the '_imageFile' is not null. Thanks for any solution you can give!

```html
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class AddDataPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddDataPageState createState() => _AddDataPageState();
}

class _AddDataPageState extends State<AddDataPage> {
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    File _imageFile;

    ///NOTE: Only supported on Android & iOS
    ///Needs image_picker plugin {https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker}
    final picker = ImagePicker();

    Future pickImage() async {
      final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
      print(pickedFile.path);

      setState(() {
        _imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
        print(pickedFile.path);
      });
    }

    Future uploadImageToFirebase(BuildContext context) async {
      String fileName = basename(_imageFile.path);
      Reference firebaseStorageRef =
      FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('uploads/$fileName');
      UploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(_imageFile);
      TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask;
      taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(
            (value) => print("Done: $value"),
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Add Details"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 50,),
            Container(
              child:Container(
                height: 200,
                child: Container(
                  child: _imageFile != null
                      ? Container(
                      child: Image.file(_imageFile),
                  height: 200,color: Colors.red,)
                      : FlatButton(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.add_a_photo,
                      size: 50,
                    ),
                    onPressed: pickImage,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            _buildTextField(username,"User Name",context),
            SizedBox(height: 10,),
            _buildTextField(product,"Product",context),
            SizedBox(height: 10,),
            _buildTextField(productDetails,"Product Details",context),
            SizedBox(height: 10,),
            _buildTextField(price,"Price",context),
            SizedBox(height: 10,),
            _buildTextField(moq,"MOQ",context),
            SizedBox(height: 10,),
            _buildTextField(market,"Market",context),
            SizedBox(height: 10,),
            _buildTextField(vendor,"Vendor",context),
            SizedBox(height: 10,),
            _buildTextField(imageClass,"Image Class",context),
            SizedBox(height: 10,),
            _buildTextField(confidence,"Confidence",context),
            SizedBox(height: 10,),
            MaterialButton(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              height: 50,
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              onPressed: addData,
              child: Center(child: Text("Submit",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,color: Colors.white),)),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
TextEditingController username = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController product = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController productDetails = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController price = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController moq = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController market = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController vendor = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController imageClass = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController confidence = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController imageUrl = TextEditingController();

Map<String, dynamic> dataToAdd;
CollectionReference collectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("data");

addData(){
  dataToAdd = {
    "username" : username.text,
    "product" : product.text,
    "productDetails" : productDetails.text,
    "price" : price.text,
    "moq" : moq.text,
    "market" : market.text,
    "vendor" : vendor.text,
    "imageClass" : imageClass.text,
    "confidence" : confidence.text,
    "imageUrl" : imageUrl.text,
  };

  collectionReference.add(dataToAdd).whenComplete(() => print("data added successfully"));
}


_buildTextField(TextEditingController controller, String labelText,BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.transparent, border: Border.all(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor)),
    child: TextField(
      controller: controller,
      style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          labelText: labelText,
          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          // prefix: Icon(icon),
          border: InputBorder.none),
    ),
  );
}
```

Here is my Pubspec.yaml File, every dependency is latest.

```html
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  form_field_validator: ^1.0.1
  firebase_core: ^0.7.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.20.0+1
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.9
  cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+22
  firebase_storage: ^7.0.0


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your image variable to State level, intead of Build function. It's called every time, you call setState(), hence setting your image to null again

```
class _AddDataPageState extends State<AddDataPage> {
  // Add this line
  File _imageFile;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   // Remove this line
   // File _imageFile; 

   ....
  }
}
```